# What is this keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, layout

Letters are azerty and symbols are qwerty, what is the name of this layout?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a long search i think there is no such layout as your keyboard and i think it is a UK qwerty keyboard with keys "A" and "Q" , "W" and "Z"  , ";" and "M" had been swapped because the user used to type using AZERTY keyboard .
i've seen a laptop with a keyboard as yours with only one difference, after "N" there is ";" then comes "<" which makes me think that both our keyboards are modified (swapped keys) and the original is the one in this picture

[uk layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsYRU.png)

to make clear that the keys "M" and ";" had been swapped
you can see from the picture you've posted that the key "M" which has also "0" in it ("M/0") , should be under all the numbers (in orange color) and the key ";" which has minus sign"-" in it should be between "P/*" and "?/+"

you can use autohotkey to remap your keyboard  but you may find  some difficulties if you use someone else's laptop .

Answer (score 2):

A quick Internet search for keyboard layouts results in:

> AZERTY, used in French-speaking countries across Europe and Africa, is
> one such version.

[image]

[Source](http://mentalfloss.com/article/52483/6-non-qwerty-keyboard-layouts)

Comment: That's not the same - everything apart from the letters is different.

Comment: the symbols are different from AZERTY, and there are no é, è or à in the OP's layout

Comment: It is still AZERTY. Accents are supplied by key modification with ALT. There is no requirement to print them on key itself. The keys on the side are supplementary - there is no design requirement how to place them on the side of the AZERTY. It differs between manufacturers.

Comment: That looks like a UK layout keyboard to me with just some keys changed around to look like the french keyboard...

Comment: Not every QWERTY keyboard is the same. It is the layout of the letters that determine the keyboard layout.